# How to save results of streaming query as PDF / XLSX (for report generation)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Curious to know if we can generate PDF or XLSX files for report using spark streaming / spark structured streaming. As per the official document there is File Sink but is PDF and XLSX supported? if so can we make use of it for report generations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if we can generate PDF or XLSX files for report using spark streaming / spark structured streaming

If you want to generate PDF/XLSX files in a distributed streaming manner, you could really use Spark Structured Streaming.

> As per the official document there is File Sink but is PDF and XLSX supported?

No. There is no direct support for PDF/XLSX formats so you'd have to write a custom data source yourself (with a streaming sink).

> if so can we make use of it for report generations?

I've never heard of such data source before, but it's certainly possible to write one yourself.

---

Think of Spark as a general-purpose computation platform and whatever can be modelled (designed) as a distributed computation should certainly be doable using Spark machinery.